# Particle at the end of a sentence

Tags: particles, particle-が, particle-で

I've seen some sentences end with particles like *が* and *で*. The most common particle that I see is *に*. For example, if someone asked:

> どこにいる？ → Where are you?

I could reply,

> 友達{ともだち}の家{いえ}に → (I'm at) my friend's house.

I'm still lost on the particles *で*, and *が*. Help would really be appreciated if someone could explain how those two particles are used at the end of a sentence.

Comment: The answer seems to be an incomplete sentence. The complete sentence should be 友達の家にいる。So for complete sentences, I don't think に can be placed at the end. Correct if I am wrong.

Comment: 普通は「今、どこ(にいるの)？」って聞かれたら「友達の家。」、「誰が勝ったの？」って聞かれたら「俺。」っていうと思います

Answer (score 2):

This is essentially an omission of a word, in this case being the verb following the particle. This is common in speech as answers to questions, and often involves omission of the main verb of a sentence.

> どこにいる？
>
> 友達の家に（いる。）

---

> 誰が勝ったか？
>
> 俺が（勝った。）

---

> 何語で話しかけられた？
>
> 英語で（話しかけられた。）

It is also common, in speech, to add a similar clause *after* the verb has been spoken. This can be done for clarification. This pattern does not require the sentence to be an answer to a question and can just be added by the speaker in anticipation of the listener not getting the full picture.

> A: 登録しました。
>
> B: （何を？）
>
> A: 名前を
>
> B: （どこに？）
>
> A: データベースに
>
> B: （何で？）
>
> A: SQLクエリーで